# How to export table of files and their details/properties to excel?

Tags: file, export, metadata, explorer

I have a list of email files (.eml) in a folder, these files have the metadata of who the email is from.  I want to export the list of "From addresses" into excel.  I can see the data in Windows Explorer details view, but I can not copy the From address out of the table.

I also tried the command prompts "dir" and "wimc datafile get" but neither of those output the From address.

[image]